# Textarea not updating when passed a string with a newline from POST?

Tags: php, html, http, post, textarea

I'm running into some troubles with my code, which I narrowed down and simplified in the two following segments:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="form" method="post" action="upload.php" target="iframe">
<textarea id="text1" name="text1"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<textarea id="text2"></textarea>

<iframe name="iframe" id="iframe" style="display:none;" ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php:**

```
<?php
$message= $_POST['text1'];

echo <<<_END
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var parDoc = window.parent.document;
parDoc.getElementById('text2').value = '$message';
</script>
_END;
?>
```

The overall goal of the code above is to present in text2, what I submitted from text1. This works with the exception of a message in text1 that contains newlines. When attempting to submit a message with newlines text2 is not updated. I can't seem to trace the error and I'm really stuck in a mental rut with this one. Any ideas? Again, this is a simplified version of my overall code. I whittled the error down to this problem.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: Nope, no javascript/php errors

Comment: Are you sure?  I'm getting an unterminated string literal javascript error because of the line break.

Comment: Yeah I was just about to post, I'm getting an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

Comment: I found a solution and posted an answer, but there is probably a much better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in upload.php

```
<?php
$message= nl2br($_POST['text1']);
$message = str_replace("\r\n",'',$message);

echo '
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var parDoc = window.parent.document;
var text = "' . $message . '";
text = text.replace(/<br \/>/ig,"\\n");
parDoc.getElementById("text2").value = text;
</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If you are happy with this solution, please click the tick mark to the left of my answer to accept it.  Thanks